# Reading Multiple Json Files And Converting To POJO Springboot batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a folder with thousands of text files with JSON content that I need to read, convert into a POJO and then save into a MySQL database. I intend to use a Spring Batch application.

Here is the issue so far, the research I have done only shows reading multiple CSV files or XML files and no JSON data. Specifically, I need to convert this method for parsing a CSV file into a JSON parser.

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Person>();
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Person>() {{
        setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
            setNames(new String[] {"firstname", "lastname", "email", "age"});
        }});
        setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
            setTargetType(Person.class);
        }});
    }});
    return reader;
}
```

This code parses a JSON file:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\path\\sample.json"));
```

The method might be something like this

```
@Bean
Public FileReader<Person> reader() {
    FileReader<Person> reader = new FileReader<Person>();

    /**** need help on what to do here ****/

    return reader;
}
```

Also seeing that I am reading all the files in a directory, I am passing the value of that directory in this format

```
@Value(value="C:\\path\\*.json")
private Resource[] resources;
```

So I need help on how to use this value (directory for all files) instead of what I showed earlier (single file location)

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\path\\sample.json"));
```

Comment: With some research you can find the answer

Comment: what does `private Resource[] resources;` contains? does it contain array of each file path?

Comment: it contains an array of all the file paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `MultiResourceItemReader` with a `JsonItemReader` as delegate. Here is a quick example:

```
@Bean
public JsonItemReader<Person> jsonItemReader(Resource[] resources) {
   JsonItemReader<Person> delegate = new JsonItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
      .jsonObjectReader(new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>(Person.class))
      .name("personItemReader")
      .build();

   MultiResourceItemReader<Person> reader = new MultiResourceItemReader<Person>();
   reader.setDelegate(delegate);
   reader.setResources(resources);
   return reader;
}
```

You can find more details about the `JsonItemReader` in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#JsonItemReader).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The type should be Resource[]

Comment: @jeanpic Good catch! I updated the answer accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#multiFileInput - I only found this after I found this answer